# Error in result set of mysql query

Tags: mysql

My mysql table 'admin' has two rows:

[image]

On executing the query

```
SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE 'admin.Sno'='1'
```

Result is:

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0000 sec)

I cannot understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you quoting tablename `'admin.Sno'`. if you want to escape it then use backquote and not single quote.

Again, I assume `sno` is a int column; in that case no need of quoting it again.

your query should look like

```
SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `Sno`=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove **admin**

```
SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE Sno='1'
```

or use backsticks

```
SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `admin`.`Sno`='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

If `Sno` is `int` remove '

```
SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `admin`.`Sno`=1
```

---

otherwise use

```
SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `Sno`='1'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `admin` 
WHERE `admin`.`Sno`='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `admin` 
WHERE `admin`.`Sno`='1'
```

OR dont use the table name as

```
SELECT * FROM `admin` 
 WHERE Sno ='1'
```

Backticks are not needed unless you use some reserved keyword.